# TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__ is not a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, checkbox, toggle

I'm working on a todo list in my current project.
I can display the todo list but when I click the checkbox to mark a task as complete I get this `TypeError`:

[image: this TypeError]

I've tried to use Google and Stack to find an answer but still can't figure out what it is I'm doing wrong. Why is `toggleComplete` not a function?

**Reducer / todosOne.js**

```
    import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export const todosOne = createSlice({
    name: 'todos',
    initialState: [
        { id: 1, text: 'This is a todo item', complete: false },
        { id: 2, text: 'This is a todo item', complete: false },
        { id: 3, text: 'This is a todo item', complete: false },
        { id: 4, text: 'This is a todo item', complete: false },
        { id: 5, text: 'This is a todo item', complete: false },
    ],

    toggleComplete: (store, action) => {
        const checkedItem = store.items.find(item => item.id === action.payload)
        if (checkedItem) {
            checkedItem.complete = !checkedItem.complete
        }
    }
})
```

**Component / TodoListOne.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

import { todosOne } from '../Reducers/todosOne'

export const TodoListOne = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const items = useSelector(store => store.todos);

    const onChecked = complete => {
        dispatch(todosOne.actions.toggleComplete(complete))
    }

    return (
        <>
            {items.map(todos => (
                <TodoContainer key={todos.id}>
                    <List>
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox"
                            checked={todos.complete}
                            onChange={() => onChecked(todos.id)}
                            />
                        </label>
                    </List>
                    <TodoText>{todos.text}</TodoText>
                </TodoContainer>
            ))}
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be

```js
export const todosOne = createSlice({
    name: 'todos',
    initialState: [
        { id: 1, text: 'This is a todo item', complete: false },
        { id: 2, text: 'This is a todo item', complete: false },
        { id: 3, text: 'This is a todo item', complete: false },
        { id: 4, text: 'This is a todo item', complete: false },
        { id: 5, text: 'This is a todo item', complete: false },
    ],
// here!
 reducers: {
    toggleComplete: (store, action) => {
        const checkedItem = store.items.find(item => item.id === action.payload)
        if (checkedItem) {
            checkedItem.complete = !checkedItem.complete
        }
    }
// here!
   }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated!

I also had to remove items from checkedItem, it's now ''const checkedItem = store.find(item => item.id === action.payload)''

Comment: True, I hadn't checked for that part ^^